# Not able to read messages from kafka consumer in kafka cluster setup

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-cluster

I have created two kafka brokers in a kafka cluster. When one broker is down I am not able to get any data to kafka consumer.
I am using this command to read messages from consumer:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test_kafka_cluster \
    --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.2:9092 --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 1):

Here as per your console consumer configuration, IP address used here are 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 and two bootstrap servers are configured as 9092.

Verify both the ip's are reachable

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test_kafka_cluster \
--bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.2:9092 --from-beginning
```

Ideally when we run tow kafka broker instance it will be running in two different ports.

Presuming Kafka is running in local
Eg: localhost:9092 localhost:9093

Kafka instances running on two different host:
Eg: 127.0.0.3:9092, 127.0.0.2:9092

**If Kafka is running on docker/docker toolbox:**

Console consumer on Docker toolbox:

```
docker exec <container-name> kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 192.168.99.100:9093 --topic <topic-name> --from-beginning
```

Console consumer on Docker:

```
docker exec <container-name> kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 localhost 9092 --topic <topic-name> --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parameters that affect topics availability for a consumer:

- `min.insync.replicas` (minISR): Minimum number of in-sync partition's replicas.
- `replication.factor` (RF): Total number of partition's replicas.

If you want your consumer to survive a broker outage, then you must have `RF > minISR`. With `RF=2 and minISR=2` you can't tolerate any broker down, with `RF=3 and minISR=2` you can tolerate 1 broker down, with `RF=5 and minISR=2` you can tolerate 3 brokers down, and so on.

Note that the internal `__consumer_offsets` topic is used to store consumer offsets and has a default RF value of 3, which is not achievable in your cluster of 2 nodes. So you also need to set `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1` at the cluster level.

Comment: I have only two brokers in my cluster, what should I do to read data in consumer if one broker when down?

Comment: I have created a topic like this: bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper x.x.x.:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 1 --topic test --config min.insync.replicas=1, Then also it's not working.

Comment: That's because the internal `__consumer_offsets` isn't available as its default RF is 3. You also need to set `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1` in your case. Answer updated.